# How can I create a text entry dialog in Android?

Tags: android, modal-dialog

What is the best way to create a modal text entry dialog for android?

I want to block until the user enters the text and hits the ok button, then extract the text from the dialog, just like a modal dialog in awt.

Thanks!

Comment: you mean inputbox type ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
final Dialog commentDialog = new Dialog(this);
commentDialog.setContentView(R.layout.reply);
Button okBtn = (Button) commentDialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
okBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                    //do anything you want here before close the dialog
                                    commentDialog.dismiss();
                            }
 });
Button cancelBtn = (Button) commentDialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                    commentDialog.dismiss();
                            }
 });
```

reply.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"       android:background="#ffffff">

    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/your_comment" android:id="@+id/body" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:lines="3" />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <Button android:id="@+id/ok" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/send"  android:layout_weight="1"
                     />
            <Button android:id="@+id/cancel" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@android:string/cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add this to display the dialog.
commentDialog.show();

Comment: Why doesn't it share the same style of the rest?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom dialog with XML layout. And as you want to block it until the user enters the text and hits the ok button, you can make it **`setCancelable(false)`**.

Check Google Search links: [Dialog With EditText](https://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=custom%20dialog%20with%20EditText)

Comment: setCancelable(false) is only superficial? I mean can it really PAUSE everything? In my app, I hope the the activity, where data are collected, that is behind the dialog to be paused.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean a Modal dialog box.

I would say Look at [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) As a start, the newer way of doing it is using an  [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) which gives you more control over the dialog life cycle.

The key method you are looking for is `dialog.setCancelable(false);`

Comment: setCancelable(false) is only superficial? I mean can it really PAUSE everything? In my app, I hope the activity, where data are collected, that is behind the dialog to be paused. i.e. the data collection is stopped until the user closes the dialog. Will it achieve that?

Comment: @perfectionming I think you need to open a new question.

Comment: @perfectionm1ng You need to pause "everything" by your own code. Because this modal dialog cannot do that for you. Maybe you can pause the data collection just before call show() dialog.